# Using a bat file with Powershell script or nsis

Tags: powershell

I execute this script in Powershell ISE and it works:

```
$listGGProvisionned = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | where { $_.PackageName –like "*MyApp*" }
if ($listGGProvisionned)
{
      foreach ($PackageProvisionned in $listGGProvisionned)
      {
            Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName $PackageProvisionned.PackageName
      }
}
```

I save this code in a file test.ps1 and I launch the command windows as admin using this command:

```
powershell.exe "c:\temp\test.ps1"
```

I have these errors:

```
Au caractère C:\temp\test.ps1:1 : 83
+ ... $_.PackageName â?"like "*MyApp*" }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Jeton inattendu « â?"like "*MyApp*" }
if ($listGGProvisionned -ne $null)
{
      foreach ($PackageProvisionned in $listGGProvisionned)
      {
            Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName $PackageProvisionned.PackageName
      }
}
$listGGPackage = Get-AppxPackage | where { $_.Name â?"like » dans l'expression ou l'instruction.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The answer is: there is an error... Please describe precisely what your script is intended to do and what it actually does! Learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Comment: This has nothing to do with batch file.

Comment: the script doesn't work in the cmd windows

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" Does it give an error? Does the script run but provide the incorrect output? Does the computer explode with sparks and blue smoke?

Comment: cmd and
C:\Windows\system32>powershell c:\temp\test.ps1 and
error Jeton inattendu « â?"like "*MyApp*" }

Comment: @lg0173, your error messages seem to be in your language.  You are going to have to translate them to English for anyone to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works

I execute the next command
The code is executed in a file powershell script

C:\Windows\system32>powershell.exe "c:\temp\test.ps1"

the character "-" is not good for me ....

Thanks